# Comparing the days difference between 2 dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In my where clause of the query I need to check if difference between 2 days is > 7 days. I tried the following and also tried datediff, dateadd, trunc, tochar but get different errors each time.
Any help is apprecaited.
For the follwoing I get ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected:

date1-date2 > 7

Posting the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM frm_rg_ps_rg ps_rg
WHERE 

((SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM frm_rg_ps_rg b
  WHERE ps_rg.patient_id = b.patient_id
  AND ps_rg.formdata_seq = b.formdata_seq
  AND ps_rg.psdate IS NOT NULL
  AND b.psdate IS NOT NULL
  AND ps_rg.psresult IS NOT NULL
  AND b.psresult IS NOT NULL) = 1)


OR NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM frm_rg_ps_rg c
  WHERE (ps_rg.psdate IS NOT NULL AND c.psdate IS NOT NULL AND ps_rg.psresult IS NOT NULL AND c.psresult IS NOT NULL)
  AND ps_rg.patient_id = c.patient_id
  AND ps_rg.formdata_seq = c.formdata_seq
  AND ps_rg.elemdata_seq!=c.elemdata_seq
  AND ps_rg.psresult != c.psresult    
  --AND to_char(ps_rg.psdate ,'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_char(c.psdate ,'yyyy-mm-dd') > 7
  --AND Trunc(ps_rg.psdate) > Trunc(c.psdate)+7
  AND ps_rg.psdate - c.psdate > 7  
  )

AND ps_rg.psresult IS NOT NULL
AND ps_rg.psdate IS NOT NULL;
```

---

```
create table frm_rg_ps_rg
(
    PATIENT_ID     NUMBER 
   ,STUDY_ID       NUMBER 
   ,PROCSTEP_ID    NUMBER 
   ,FORMDATA_SEQ   NUMBER 
   ,ELEMDATA_SEQ   NUMBER 
   ,PSUNITOS       VARCHAR2(3950 CHAR) 
   ,PSDATE         DATE 
   ,PSND           VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
   ,PSRESULT       NUMBER 
   ,PSUNITS        VARCHAR2(120) 
);
```

Comment: What data types are these values? `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: A "non-numeric" character would be in a string not a date.  Hence, one or both of your columns are strings, and not dates or numbers.

Comment: These are DATE fields

Comment: Please show us your full query. If both `date1` and `date2` are really `DATE` types then this error should not appear.

Comment: + table definition please

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit . . . Or, more specifically, if this error does appear it is not referring to this calculation -- assuming the two columns are dates.

Comment: There is nothing wrong syntactically with this query. Please add the table definition.

Comment: Please also add a small sample of data for `psdate`

Comment: Added table definition in a comment below

Comment: Sample for psdate is 27-MAY-15

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query nor with the table DDL. I managed to create the table and run the query "as is". I'm suspecting you are running not just the query but additional code that exists in the same screen.

Comment: Nope just the query in my sqldeveloper. I get ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: Can you please run it from SQL*Plus and show us the results?

Comment: It sounds very much like corrupted data. It **is** possible to have garbage in the database - for example, a date column (specifically defined as date datatype) containing the character `'x'` (or even `'/'`). You can test this easily - for example `select psdate + 1 from....` - you should get the same error when you run this either on the first table or on the second (or both). It would help if you can run this - either you can reproduce the error or you can't, in both cases we'll have narrowed down the possibilities.

Comment: It fetches records after trying select psdate + 1 from frm_rg_ps_rg, no errors

Comment: Then ORA-01858 must come from somewhere else. Check all of you code. Do you get any error stack with line number et. al.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string columns hold date in format 'yyyy-mm-dd' (change it if needed)

```
to_date(date1,'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_date(date2,'yyyy-mm-dd') > 7
```

---

Demo for the OP

```
create table t (dt1 date,dt2 date);
insert into t (dt1,dt2) values (sysdate,sysdate-10);
```

---

```
select * from t where (select dt1-dt2 from dual) > 7;

+---------------------+---------------------+
| DT1                 | DT2                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-12-14 10:59:34 | 2016-12-04 10:59:34 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

---

```
select * from t where dt1-dt2 > 7;

+---------------------+---------------------+
| DT1                 | DT2                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-12-14 10:59:34 | 2016-12-04 10:59:34 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way to get this error with this statement:

```
date1 - date2 > 7
```

And with both being dates.  This could occur if you have hidden characters in the row -- that is, invisible characters between the `>` and the `7` or right after the `7`.

You might try removing that line and retyping it to see if the error goes away.

Comment: I have posted the query. And again, the dates I;m trying to compare are of type DATE

Comment: Name         Null     Type                
------------ -------- ------------------- 
PATIENT_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER              
STUDY_ID     NOT NULL NUMBER              
PROCSTEP_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER              
FORMDATA_SEQ NOT NULL NUMBER              
ELEMDATA_SEQ          NUMBER              
PSUNITOS              VARCHAR2(3950 CHAR) 
PSDATE                DATE                
PSND                  VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)    
PSRESULT              NUMBER              
PSUNITS               VARCHAR2(120)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved now:
I tried this:
 AND (select (ps_rg.psdate - c.psdate) from dual)>7

Comment: **This cannot be the answer**. If this works than `ps_rg.psdate-c.psdate>7` should definitly work. This was not the issue. See my answer for a demo.